# spring batch with multiple reader to read from ldap based on filter

Tags: spring, oracle, ldap, spring-batch

I have a requirement to create a spring batch wherein the job is to read data from LDAP based on filters provided.
can anyone help to find how to configure multiple readers where each reader will have a different filter and returns the list of objects  and process the list and store it to different domain

For example :

```
List<Users> reader1(LdapTemplate ldaptemplate){
LdapItemReader reader = new LdapItemReader<>(
filter1 = ..;

)



List<Users> reader2(LdapTemplate ldaptemplate){
LdapItemReader reader = new LdapItemReader<>(
filter2 =  ..;

)
}
```

processor is to process the list after each reader based on some conditions.
writer store the processed list to a different object.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

A chunk-oriented step in Spring Batch can only have one item reader. So you either need to create a custom reader that aggregates items from two datasources or create two different steps where each step uses a particular reader.